# JSP tag attribute cannot be set more than once?

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I have some old JSP files with tags such as

`<mytag:editbox name="SEL_1" param="onclick='clickit();" param="size='4'" />.`

These JSP runs very well in Websphere 5.0. When I move it into Websphere 8.0, something is wrong. The java source compiled by JSP like this:

```
editbox.setName("SEL_1");
editbox.setParam("size='4'");  //replaced by the last one
editbox.setParam("size='4'");
```

The last [attributes] overwrites those before it. I also test the JSP in Websphere 6.0 and Tomcat. WAS6 is same as 8.0, and Tomcat says:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp (line: 17, column: 20) Attribute qualified names must be unique within an element
```

The attribute of tag can't be set more than once.

Is this the requirement of JSP 2.0+ specification? (I think the JSP container in WAS5.0 is JSP 1.2 .)

I can merge the two param attribute into one to correct the problem, but how to get the correct result without changing the JSP source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having multiple attributes with the same name was *never* supported by the JSP spec. If it worked on Websphere 5 then that would have depended on proprietary behaviour permissible by that server version, and not by any others. I take it the tag class does something like adding the values to a collection, or some such.

You'll need to refactor the tag to be spec-compliant, either by using a delimited string, or using nested tags.

Answer (score 3):

JSP tags are XML elements. And an XML element can't have multiple attributes with the same name. IMHO, your code happened to work only by accident in previous Websphere versions, probably due to a sloppy validation and interpretation of the JSP tags.

Answer (score 0):

To have the same behavior with WAS 8 you can include this JSP attribute in your application deployment descriptor (`ibm-ext-web.xmi`):

`allowMultipleAttributeValues` set to `true`.

Or set the Web container custom property `com.ibm.wsspi.jsp.allowMultipleAttributeValues` to `true`.

Source: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM65454

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was using struts tags with Display tag library tags at the same time, so I faced this issue. Once I chose one to use the error went away. Using same tags from two different libraries causes ambiguity.